# The shortcuts of annotation tools changed itself

Tags: shortcut, annotation

Sorry for this silly title. I tried to pinpoint the cause of this behavior but it seems so random.

Usually my shortcut of Annotation Eraser is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>:

[image]

But *sometimes* it becomes <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>:

[image]

And after I add and erase some annatotions, it becomes <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> again, back and forth, leaving me confused.

I'm pretty sure that I don't change any of preferences.

Comment: After what steps does the shortcut change? Seems like a bug, that should be reported on the official bug tracker through *Help > Report a Bug*.